# I'm learning javascript. My if with && seems correct, but

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Below is the code for my "Code your Own Adventure" in code academy.  When I fill in the prompts with PIZZA, YES and YES it should tell me "Great, come get your pizza!", but it tells me "NO pizza for you!"  For the PIZZA case I have tried "Yes" and 'YES' inside the if statement and neither seems to return "Great, come get your pizza!", but it tells me "NO pizza for you!"
I'm sorry this probably is a basic question and won't help anyone other than a beginner, but help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
var user = prompt("Would you like to buy PIZZA, a HAMBURGER or a TACO?").toUpperCase();
switch(user) {
case 'PIZZA':
    var money = prompt("Do you have at least $10? (YES/NO)").toUpperCase;
    var cheeseOk = prompt("Do you tolerate cheese? (YES/NO)").toUpperCase;

    if (money === 'YES' && cheeseOk === 'YES') {
        console.log("Great, come get your pizza");
    } else {
        console.log("NO pizza for you!");
    }
    break;
case 'HAMBURGER':
    var getCheese = prompt("Do you want cheese on that? (YES/NO)").toUpperCase;
    var hungry = prompt("Are you really hungry? (YES/NO)").toUpperCase;
    if (getCheese === 'YES' || hungry === 'YES') {
        console.log("Great, come get your burger!");
    } else {
        console.log("NO burger for you!");
    }

    break;
case 'TACO':
    prompt("AUTHENTIC or TACO BELL?").toUpperCase;
    break;
default:
    console.log("We don't have that. Sorry.");
    break;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.toUpperCase` is a function that you should call like this:

```
... .toUpperCase();
```

Otherwise both `money` and `cheeseOk` will get assigned a reference to that function which is obviously **not equal** to `"YES"`!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the () on the calls to `.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: Yes!  That's it.  Thanks.